# Add text to a file with PHP SSH2

Tags: php, bash, ssh2

I am trying to create and append to a text file using PHP SSH2. The command I am sending is this:

```
$cmd = "cd $output_directory; cat > myfile.txt; echo \"My Text\" >> myfile.txt";
```

The file is created, but the text is not appended to it.

Appreciate any input as to where I am going wrong.

Comment: Your command works for me. Have you tried prepending "php" to the command?

Comment: Show the PHP code you use to run this `$cmd`.  Also note that on my linux, `cat >myfile.txt` does not work.  I have to do `cat /dev/null >myfile.txt` or my preferred `>myfile.txt`, no cat at all.  This creates the empty file, I assume you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `cat` to `touch` to create file.

Example:

```
$cmd = "cd $output_directory; touch myfile.txt; echo \"My Text\" >> myfile.txt";
```